# Update the text field on-click with set of options and update in server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display and update values in the same page. So whenever I click on the text field(values), I want a select option to be displayed. Then the selected value should be updated in both user side and server side using POST.

--> on-clicking "Your Name" it should pop up with text input box.

--> on-clicking "My Gender" It should pop up with a select option.

And,  I want anchors to be replaced with input & select Tag. I want to perform Inline edit.

```html
<p>Name : <a href="" title="">Your Name</a>
</p>
<p>Gender : <a href="" title="">My Gender</a>
</p>




<input type="text" name="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" value="" required="required" pattern="" title="" placeholder="Enter your Name">
<br>
<select name="gender" id="inputGender" class="form-control" required="required">
  <option value="male">male</option>
  <option value="female">female</option>
</select>
```

And after I type or select the text ,by clicking the button it should POST the data to the server using ajax like...

```
POST url = "/post"
name = "name"
value = "danny"
RESPONSE: status = 200
```

[image: Sample Text Field]

[image: After clicking Text]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a#yourName').on('click', function() {
   $('#inputName').show()
 })

 $('a#myGender').on('click', function() {
   $('#inputGender').show()
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name : <a href="#" title="" id="yourName">Your Name</a>
</p>
<p>Gender : <a href="#" title="" id="myGender">My Gender</a>
</p>
<input hidden type="text" name="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" value="" required="required" pattern="" title="" placeholder="Enter your Name">
<br>
<select hidden name="gender" id="inputGender" class="form-control" required="required">
  <option value="male">male</option>
  <option value="female">female</option>
</select>
```

You should add id's to the anchors and then apply the functions with jquery

```
<p>Name : <a href="#" title="" id="yourName">Your Name</a></p>
<p>Gender : <a href="#" title="" id="myGender">My Gender</a></p>


 $('a#yourName').on('click', function() {
   $('#inputName').show()
 })

 $('a#myGender').on('click', function() {
   $('#inputGender').show()
 })
```

**UPDATE**
To do inline edit you need to put the anchors and inputs into span tags with id's set to them and styling the input spans with `display:none` it should be hidden by default, then use the `replaceWith()` function to replace the anchors with the inputs html,

See the snippet below for an example.

```js
$('a#yourName').on('click', function() {
  $('span#a1').replaceWith($('#span1').html());
})

$('a#myGender').on('click', function() {
     $('span#a2').replaceWith($('#span2').html());
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name : <span id="a1"><a href="#" title="" id="yourName">Your Name</a></span>
</p>
<p id="p2">Gender : <span id="a2"><a href="#" title="" id="myGender">My Gender</a></span>
</p>
<span id="span1" style="display:none"><input type="text" name="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" value="" required="required" pattern="" title="" placeholder="Enter your Name"></span>
<br>
<span id="span2" style="display:none"><select name="gender" id="inputGender" class="form-control" required="required">
  <option value="male">male</option>
  <option value="female">female</option>
</select></span>
```

Comment: But why it is disappearing automatically

Comment: Because `href=""` is empty should be `href="#"`, updated answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks, But I want anchors to be replaced with <input> & <select> Tag. I want to perform Inline edit.

Comment: Thanks  a lot, This is what i wanted. Could I send post request to the server using ajax .